# Dropbox API - Node.js - Remember authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox-api

I'm using Node.js to upload and download some files.

The authentication part works, but everytime you start the "app", you have to re-authenticate the app.

the code:

```
<html>
<title>Dropbox</title>

<button id="signin-button">Sign in</button>
<script>
require("nw.gui").Window.get().maximize(true);


var Dropbox = require("dropbox");

// Server-side applications use both the API key and secret.
var client = new Dropbox.Client({
    key: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    secret: "XXXXXXXXXX"
});

   client.authDriver(new Dropbox.AuthDriver.NodeServer(8191));


// Try to use cached credentials.
client.authenticate({interactive: false}, function(error, client) {
  if (error) {
return showError(error);
 }
  if (client.isAuthenticated()) {
    // Cached credentials are available, make Dropbox API calls.
    console.log("Authenticated form Cache");
  } else {
// show and set up the "Sign into Dropbox" button
var button = document.querySelector("#signin-button");
button.setAttribute("class", "visible");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // The user will have to click an 'Authorize' button.
  client.authenticate(function(error, client) {
    if (error) {
      return showError(error);
    }
    console.log("Authenticated after button click.");
  });
    });
  }
});


function showError(error){
console.error(error);
}
</script>
</html>
```

The authentication sample code was on their github.  It never loads or saves the authentication data.

tl;dr How can I save the authentication data to prevent the user from having to log-in EVERY time.

Jeroen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the access token after auth via `client.credentials().token` and persist it.

Then on subsequent runs, you can use `new Dropbox.Client({ token: savedToken });` to avoid having to go through OAuth again.